# What would be the most efficient way of going about making my one line of fields into two rows 4 fields in each

Tags: html, css

Basically right now I have everything in a straight line, I  know it isn't responsive, not part of the task. I want to change it so I have 'clock hours, incentive, off clock, and regular hours' on the top row & overtime hrs, personal, vacation, and holiday' directly beneath it. And then have total hours off to the side near the signature area. I have some thoughts on how to do it but I feel like it could be done in a simple way so I don't know exactly the best way of tackling it.

```css
/* *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    } */


/* @page {
        size: 8.5in 11in;
      } */

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.signandauth {
  /*div for authorized, signature & their textboxes*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.dateSection {
  /*div for date script*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 65px;
}

.section1 {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border: 4px solid black;
  /* margin-right: 20px; */
}

.section2 {
  padding: 70px 0;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  display: inline;
}

p {
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

#date {
  float: left;
}

#authorized {
  /*text box*/
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
}

#authorizeP {
  /*the label*/
  float: right;
}

#signature {
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
}

#signP {
  float: right;
}

table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
}

td {
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<body>

  <title>Time Card</title>

  <div class="section1">
    <h2>Time Card: AWS</h2>
    <div class="dateSection">
      <p id="date"></p>
      <script>
        var date = new Date();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date.toDateString();
      </script>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Clock Hours</p>
    <label id="clockHours">0.00</label>

    <p>Incentive</p>

    <label id="Incentive">0.00</label>
    <p>Off Clock</p>

    <label id="offClock">0.00</label>
    <p>Regular Hours</p>

    <label id="regularHours">0.00</label>
    <p>Overtime Hours</p>

    <label id="overtimeHours">0.00</label>
    <p>Total Hours</p>

    <label id="totalHours">0.00</label>
    <p>Personal</p>
    <label id="personal">0.00</label>
    <p>Vacation</p>
    <label id="vacation">0.00</label>
    <p>Holiday</p>
    <label id="holiday">0.00</label>
    <div class="signandauth">
      <p id="authorizeP">Authorized</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label id="authorized"></label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p id="signP">Employee Signature</p>
      <br>

      <label id="signature"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
  <div class="section2">
    <table>

      <tr>

        <td>000</td>
        <td>000</td>
        <td>000</td>
        <td>000</td>
        <td>000</td>
        <td>000</td>
        <td>000</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not put them in a 2x4 table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about putting them in a 2x4 table?

Answer (score 0):

```
<br>
```

will break onto a new line, that should do what you're hoping.

Comment: wow i am actually embarrased how simple it was. I knew i was overthinking it

Comment: Haha I do the exact same

Comment: my only issue now is that I need my label boxes to be flush with the top row I want the boxes to be symmetric with the row above.

Comment: Have you attempted Grid Box?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table >
  <tr>
    <th>Clock Hours</th>     
    <th>Incentive</th> 
    <th>Off Clock</th>
    <th>Regular Hours</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90px; padding: 5px"><label id="clockHours">0.00</label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90px; padding: 5px"><label id="Incentive">0.00</label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90px; padding: 5px"><label id="offClock">0.00</label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90px; padding: 5px"><label id="regularHours">0.00</label>
  </tr>

</table>
<br>
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Overtime Hours</th>      
    <th>Personal</th> 
    <th>Vacation</th>
    <th>Holiday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90px; padding: 5px"><label id="clockHours">0.00</label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90px; padding: 5px"><label id="Incentive">0.00</label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90px; padding: 5px"><label id="offClock">0.00</label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90px; padding: 5px"><label id="regularHours">0.00</label>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: got it finally.